# .Net Micro Framework and Web Services

Tags: web-services, .net-micro-framework

I want to connect from a .Net Micro Framework application to an existing web service hosted in WCF on a Windows Service / IIS. Is this possible and could someone please point me in the right direction with regard to the documentation on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: On the .Net Micro Framework you do not have that option ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this articles can help you

- "Implementing Web Services on Your Devices" (.Net Micro):
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh423016.aspx
- "Connected Devices Using the .NET Micro
  Framework": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232761.aspx